# Got inconsistent Mercurial subrepository state (RepoLookupError) twice per day. How is that possible?

Tags: mercurial, kiln

Recently migrated to Mercurial.

Due to heavy use of externals in old SVN repo we are using Subrepos accordingly and have a CI server that does pulls / pushes to central repositories often. So it's a bit hard to trace what exactly happened and developers can't reproduce the exact steps.

But, after pulling we got errors likes this:

```
RepoLookupError: unknown revision '766981bc81dc78fe24d5fe5c7d68e36c66858e73'
abort: unknown revision '766981bc81dc78fe24d5fe5c7d68e36c66858e73'!
```

And such changesets could not be found anywhere, nor on server nor in local repositories. Got this situation twice per day.

Somehow, from the server comes a .hgsubstate that refers to unknown subrepository changeset.

And we didn't do anything potentially harmful, just usual commits / pulls / merges.

As of our understanding - this is an impossible situation (you can't commit a .hgsubstate referring to uncommitted or not existing subrepository changeset).

Any ideas what we could be doing wrong or how this could happen?

**edit**:not using mq either

Comment: Does one of your users use mq? I've bolluxed up stuff good with mq + subrepos.

Comment: Mm, no, i don't think server is on NFS. Server is running on Windows Server 2008 R2, in virtual machine, with NTFS file system. It's a kiln installation, to be specific. Host is also Win2008R2

Comment: Perhaps you have managed to commit properly, but not push properly, only pushing the main repository, and not the sub-repos? That way the main repository would refer to committed changesets, they're just not available to you (yet.)

Comment: This is also impossible. Mercurial always pushes subrepositories before pushing main.

Comment: I sounds like we'll need more information and discussion. Please take it to the Mercurial mailinglist: mercurial@selenic.com — that's much better suited for such discussions.

Comment: Martin, the situation is not reproducing itself. I guess, there is no need for further investigation. But thanks, if we'll again encounter this, i will write to the mailing list.

Answer (score 2):

To create an unknown (invisible) revision, do like this.

**Client 1**

1. Commmit a change in a subrepo
2. Link the commit in the subrepo with a commit in the subrepo (the subrepo changeset id will be updated in the .hgsubstate file)
3. Rollback the subrepo commit (now you got yourself a link in the master repo to a non-existing changeset in the subrepo)
4. Push both repositories to the server

**Client 2**

1. Pull from the server

Error occur!